# Which spells may I purchase for a PFS party member?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, pathfinder-society

In Pathfinder Society, players aren't generally allowed to provide permanent help to other players.  However, there is a note in the [Guide to PFS Organized Play](http://paizo.com/products/v5748btpy84k4) which says players may share gold for some spellcasting services:

> You are also permitted to spend your character's gold to help a party member purchase spellcasting services such as *raise dead* or *remove disease*.

This makes sense, because players may be unable to adventure for the gold they need to, say, raise themselves from the dead.  But the phrase "spellcasting services *such as*.." makes me think there might be some limits to this option.

Which spells are available for this type of cost pooling?

Comment: This could be read as a "how do I abuse organized play" question, which makes me roll my eyes a little bit, but it is the type of thing that needs answers, and it is usually better to have answers before the question is asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the author was implying that cash could be pooled to cast any of the common spellcasting services shown in Table 5-2. The specific rules for NPC Spellcasting Services, which are on p25 of the guide (under Spellcasting Services), also mention pooling gold to cast spells to clear conditions. It also clarifies that you can only have spells of up to 6th level cast. Apart from that, there are no additional limitations listed, beyond the rules from p163 of the Core Rulebook, in the Spellcasting Services section. The very next rules section, though, outlines some spells that can never be cast in the campaign - no Awaken, Permanency or Reincarnate.